# MongoDB Java Async Driver: Block<Document> vs SingleResultCallBack<Document>

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I just started learning mongodb java driver's async API. Most of the examples override **SingleResultCallback's** onResult method as given bellow:

```
 // get it (since it's the only one in there since we dropped the rest earlier on)
    collection.find().first(new SingleResultCallback<Document>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Document document, final Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(document.toJson());
        }
    });
```

this callback is executed when the query gets executed and response/error is returned.

But, in case of FindIterable we need to override Block's apply method as 1st argument and SingleResultCallback's onResult method as sencond argument.

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("restaurants").find();
    // @code: end

    // @pre: Iterate the results and apply a block to each resulting document
    // @code: start
    iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(final Document document) {
            System.out.println(document);
        }
    }, new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Operation Finished");
        }
    });
```

I am not able to understand why we need both Block and SingleResultCallBack at the same time. What things/operation can we perform in Block that we couldn't do with SingleResultCallBack?

Answer (score 0):

`Block` is applied to each item iterated over. `SingleResultCallback` is executed once the iteration is complete.

The [javadoc](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoIterable.html#forEach-com.mongodb.Block-com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback-) for `com.mongodb.async.client.MongoIterable` says:

> Iterates over all documents in the view, applying the given block to
>   each, and completing the returned future after all documents have been
>   iterated, or an exception has occurred.